# could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster

Tags: magento2.4, warden

I am using warden for magento 2.4 in shell when I run `bin/magento s:up` I am facing following error:

could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2.4 Elasticsearch is mandatory. So you need to setup Elasticsearch. When running setup:upgrade it also needs Elasticsearch connection and alive nodes. You can set it in Magento admin Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search. Or you can add entries direct in database in core_config_data table `catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_hostname` and `catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_port` (Elasticsearch 7).
If you have it set already, check what is blocking connection.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2.4.x template comes latest so when installing Magento 2.4.x you need to install elasticsearch first.

Answer (score 0):

Check your elasticsearch installation and again compile the code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was upgrading magento from 2.3.6 to 2.4.4. (PHP 8.1, Elasticsearch 7.16) My local environment was Warden on Ubuntu 20.04. To get rid of this error "Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster" (that was popping up during bin/magento setup:upgrade) I had to do two things:

1. manually add "elasticsearch" to node <elasticsearch7_server_hostname> in vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch-7/etc/config.xml
2. disable elasticsearch6 and enable elasticsearch7 module

bin/magento module:enable {Magento_Elasticsearch,Magento_InventoryElasticsearch,Magento_Elasticsearch7}

bin/magento module:disable Magento_Elasticsearch6

Hope, that my answer will help someone :)